# Integrating $\int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin(tx)}{1+x^2} dx$ without contour integration?

Tags: definite-integrals

How do I integrate this *without* contour integration?

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin(tx)}{1+x^2} dx$$

I have tried everything, splitting the integral from $0$ to $1$ and $1$ to infinity and using the geometric series summation, rewriting $\sin(tx)$ as $\frac{e^{itx}-e^{-itx}}{2i}$ and $1+x^2$ as $(x+i)(x-i)$.

But nothing has borne fruit. I am fine with using other well known functions and even complex analysis but I want to solve this *without* contour integration or other complicated methods like Laplace transforms.

Comment: Probably Feynman trick should work, have you tried it?

Comment: I would then get cos(tx)x^2/(1+x^2),I would then while solving get cos(tx)/(1+x^2)  which is a well-known integral i suppose but it also involves contour integration

Comment: I assumed $t>0$ in my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let'ss define a function
$$ f(t)=\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{x^2+1} \sin(tx)dx$$
now let's use Laplace transfrom
$$ L_t(f(t))(s)=L_t\left(\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{x^2+1} \sin(tx)dx\right)(s)$$
then
$$ L_t(f(t))(s)=\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{x^2+1} L_t(\sin(tx))(s)dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{x^2+1} \frac{x}{x^2+s^2} dx$$
and where
$$ \frac{x}{x^2+1} \frac{x}{x^2+s^2}=\frac{1}{s^2-1} \frac{s^2}{x^2+s^2}-\frac{1}{s^2-1} \frac{1}{x^2+1} $$
So
$$ L_t(f(t))(s)=\frac{1}{s^2-1} \frac{\pi}{2} s-\frac{1}{s^2-1} \frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{s+1} $$
and by taking the inverse Laplace transform we easily get
$$ f(t)=\frac{\pi}{2} e^{-t}  , Re(t)>0 $$
or
$$ f(t)=\frac{\pi}{2} e^{-|t|}  , t\in R $$

**Addendum**

If you don't know about Laplace transfrom we can rewrite the solution by using double integral instead of that trnasform because Laplace transform means integral.

Let's use the known integral
$$ \int_0^\infty \sin(tx) e^{-st} dt=\frac{x}{x^2+s^2} $$
So
$$ \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st} dt=\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{x^2+1} \frac{x}{x^2+s^2} dx$$
then it's easy to show that
$$ \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st} dt=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{s+1} $$
but
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{\pi}{2}e^{-t} e^{-st} dt =\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{s+1}$$
So we get (for positive $s$ or it's real part being positive if it's a complex number)
$$ f(t)=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-t} $$

Comment: Im not really familiar with laplace transforms... ill add that to my question

Comment: @uggupuggu you should know the ways for solving this integral which are : Laplace transform (as I solved) and inverse laplace transform and by complex analysis and Fynman's trick which give us ODE and by special functions Ci(x) , Si(x)

Comment: I decided to suck it up and learn what laplace transforms are, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Start with $$\frac{x}{1+x^2} =\frac{x}{(x+i)(x-i)}=\frac{1}{2 (x+i)}+\frac{1}{2 (x-i)}$$
Now consider
$$I_+=\int \frac{\sin(tx)}{x+i}\,dx=\int \frac{\sin (t (y-i))}{y}\,dy$$
$$\sin (t (y-i))=\cosh (t) \sin (t y)-i \sinh (t) \cos (t y)$$
$$\int \frac{\sin (ty)}{y}\,dy=t \int \frac{\sin (u)}{u}\,du=t\,\text{Si}(u)$$
$$\int \frac{\cos (ty)}{y}\,dy=t \int \frac{\cos (u)}{u}\,du=t\,\text{Ci}(u)$$

So, we have all required antiderivatives.

Back to $x$
$$2\int \frac{x\sin(tx)}{1+x^2} dx=i \sinh (t) (\text{Ci}(-t (x-i))-\text{Ci}(t (x+i)))+$$ $$\cosh (t)
   (\text{Si}(t (x+i))-\text{Si}(i t-t x))$$ which is $0$ for $x=0$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x\sin(tx)}{1+x^2}\, dx=\frac{ \pi}{2}  (\cosh (t)-\sinh (t))= \frac \pi 2\, e^{-t}$$

**Edit**

We can even go further using asymptotics
$$\int_0^z \frac{x\sin(tx)}{1+x^2}\, dx= \frac \pi 2\, e^{-t}-\frac{\cos (t z)}{t z} A-\frac{\sin (t z)}{(t z)^2}B$$ with
$$A=1-\frac{t^2+2}{(tz)^2}+\frac{t^4+12 t^2+24}{(tz)^4
  }-\frac{t^6+30 t^4+360 t^2+720}{(tz)^6
  }+O\left(\frac{1}{z^8}\right)$$
$$B=1-\frac{3 \left(t^2+2\right)}{(tz)^2}+\frac{5 (t^4+10 t^2+24)
   }{(tz)^4}-\frac{7(t^6+30 t^4+360 t^2+720)}{(tz)^6}+O\left(\frac{1}{z^8}\right)$$

Computing the value of
$$\int_z^\infty \frac{x\sin(tx)}{1+x^2}\, dx$$ for $t=3$ and $z=10$, the exact value is    $4.0212430\times 10^{-3}$  while the above asymptotics gives $4.0212455\times 10^{-3}$ (absolute error of $2.56\times 10^{-9}$).

We can easily generalize the problem to
$$I_n=\int_z^\infty \frac{x\sin^{2n+1}(tx)}{1+x^2}\, dx$$

Comment: Ci(−t(x−i))

How did you get this? Im trying to work it out

Comment: @uggupuggu. Cosine integral function

Comment: The formula in the edit is exact or an asymptotic approximation

Comment: @Zima   asymptotics for sure. Cheers

Comment: @Zima. Asymptotics improved and tested